# Valet not working for WordPress site: Error establishing a database connection

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, laravel-valet

I am having a problem connecting to my WordPress site using Valet. I get the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'db_username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   /Users/.../Documents/WordPress/.../wp-includes/wp-db.php
>   on line 1531
>
> **Error establishing a database connection**
>
> This either
>   means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php
>   file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at
>   localhost. This could mean your host’s database server is down.
>
> - Are you sure you have the correct username and password?
> - Are you sure that you have typed the correct hostname?
> - Are you sure that the database server is running?
>
> If you’re unsure what these terms mean you
>   should probably contact your host. If you still need help you can
>   always visit the WordPress Support Forums.

This is odd, as **I am able to connect the page that is online** to this database. This makes me believe that all of the following settings should be correct:

- DB_NAME
- DB_USER
- DB_PASSWORD
- DB_HOST
- DB_CHARSET
- DB_COLLATE

I also wanted to note that I do not have any redirection issues. I had this at first and solved it by changing the "DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE" to my Valet domain.

Example:

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'valetdomain.test');
```

I am also able to connect to the database within Sequel Pro on my computer with the same login information.

Note: I can use Valet on my other pages locally as well and that works fine.

So, I have Valet working, Sequel should be working, and the site works online. I just can't seem to get them all working together :(

Is it possible that the wp-config settings or some other settings must be different when connecting a WordPress site locally, via Valet in my case, as opposed to online?

Things I have tried:

- Creating a new user within cPanel, adding them to this database, and updating wp-config accordingly
- using no password and connecting via Root
- using my server's IP address as the hostname instead of localhost
- using 127.0.0.1 as the hostname instead of localhost
- changing the siteurl and home within wp_options table to the .test domain that I'm using with Valet (this just kills my online site, but doesn't help me connect the DB for the local site in Valet)

One thing I'd like to note here is that if I use...

```
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
```

... then the error changes from the one above to simply "Error establishing a database connection." Is this somehow a "better" error, meaning that I could be closer to solving this problem?

Final note, I am using WP Multisite. Not sure if this makes any difference.

---

I was able to solve the problem by closing everything and restarting WordPress from scratch. I think the problem was that I had two versions of SQL running on my computer, one from Brew and the other from the Mac. This may have caused the problem. I'm not sure if this is the best advice, but it is what helped me.

Comment: One debugging strategy is to add a file like testconnection.php which prints `mysqli_error()` if `mysqli_connect` fails. See https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-error-establishing-a-database-connection-in-wordpress/